# resolve target entities compiler pass

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a bundle which sets some resolve target entities based on parameter values. I've found similar questions on the internet but it seems like the answers there are not working for me. Maybe i'm missing something. Please check where i'm going wrong!

Here is my build method from the bundle class:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);
    $container->addCompilerPass(new ResolveTargetEntitiesCompilerPass());
}
```

And here is the process method in the compiler pass:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $def = $container->findDefinition('doctrine.orm.listeners.resolve_target_entity');
    $def->addMethodCall('addResolveTargetEntity', array(
        'Test\BaseBundle\Entity\ContentType', $container->getParameter('test_base.content_type_entity_class'), array()
    ));
    $def->addMethodCall('addResolveTargetEntity', array(
        'Test\BaseBundle\Entity\Path', $container->getParameter('test_base.path_entity_class'), array()
    ));
}
```

As far as i know it's all i need for what i need but I get Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException with message class Test\BaseBundle\Entity\ContentType does not exist.

EDIT:

In this case ContentType is an interface. Here is the class which i passed as the test_base.content_type_entity_class parameter:

```
namespace Test\BaseExampleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Test\BaseBundle\Entity\ContentType as ContentTypeInterface;

/**
 * ContentType
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ContentType implements ContentTypeInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="action", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $action;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codename", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $codename;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setAction($action)
    {
        $this->action = $action;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAction()
    {
        return $this->action;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getCodename()
    {
        return $this->codename;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setCodename($codename)
    {
        $this->codename = $codename;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Just to make clear the value of test_base.content_type_entity_class parameter is set to Test\BaseExampleBundle\Entity\ContentType.

EDIT:

I've found out it's working when i put at least one entry in the doctrine.orm.resolve_target_entities configuration key.

Comment: Have you checked the namespace of the entity?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure that the namespaces are matching.

Comment: Is the autoloader aware of this class (i.e. will it be found when you use it like any other class in your application)? If you are not sure, you can show use the contents of the file containing the class, your `composer.json` file and the location where you store the class. By the way, you know that it is not necessary to create such a compiler pass but that you can [configure target entities in the application config](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)?

Comment: Try to use `'TestBaseBundle:ContentType'` instead of `'Test\BaseBundle\Entity\ContentType'`

Comment: The full namespace should works. Please add the `ContentType` entity with namespace and mapping in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the solution. It's in `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension::ormLoad` function. It tags the `doctrine.orm.listeners.resolve_target_entity` service definition as a listener or subscriber based on doctrine version.

```
        // BC: ResolveTargetEntityListener implements the subscriber interface since
        // v2.5.0-beta1 (Commit 437f812)
        if (version_compare(Version::VERSION, '2.5.0-DEV') < 0) {
            $def->addTag('doctrine.event_listener', array('event' => 'loadClassMetadata'));
        } else {
            $def->addTag('doctrine.event_subscriber');
        }
```

So my solution is to do the same in my compiler pass like this:

```
    if (version_compare(Version::VERSION, '2.5.0-DEV') < 0 && !$def->hasTag('doctrine.event_listener')) {
        $def->addTag('doctrine.event_listener', array('event' => 'loadClassMetadata'));
    } elseif(!$def->hasTag('doctrine.event_subscriber')) {
        $def->addTag('doctrine.event_subscriber');
    }
```