# Compiler pass - resolve target entity doesn't load

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm working on a bundle and i need to load a doctrine resolve_target_entities from a configuration parameter.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830723/resolve-target-entities-compiler-pass) should be my solution, the fact is that using the bundle it seems not to load the "compiler pass class".

This is my bundle class

```
class PersonalBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container){
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ResolveTargetEntitiesPass());
    }
}
```

This is the ResolveTargetEntitiesPass class

```
class ResolveTargetEntitiesPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Gets the custom entity defined by the user (or the default one)
        $customEntityClass = $container->getParameter('personal.custom_class');
        // Skip the resolve_target_entities part if user has not defined a different entity
        if (DefaultClassInterface::DEFAULT_ENTITY_CLASS == $customEntityClass) {
            return;
        }
        // Throws exception if the class isn't found
        if (!class_exists($customEntityClass)) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(sprintf("Can't find class %s ", $customEntityClass));
        }

        // Get the doctrine ResolveTargetEntityListener
        $def = $container->findDefinition('doctrine.orm.listeners.resolve_target_entity');
        // Adds the resolve_target_enitity parameter
        $def->addMethodCall('addResolveTargetEntity', array(
            DefaultClassInterface::DEFAULT_ENTITY_CLASS, $customEntityClass, array()
        ));
        // This was added due this problem
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656413/7070573
        if (version_compare(Version::VERSION, '2.5.0-DEV') < 0 && !$def->hasTag('doctrine.event_listener')) {
            $def->addTag('doctrine.event_listener', array('event' => 'loadClassMetadata'));
        } elseif (!$def->hasTag('doctrine.event_subscriber')) {
            $def->addTag('doctrine.event_subscriber');
        }
    }
}
```

When i use the class it raises this error

> Expected value of type "PersonalBundle\Entity\DefaultClass"
>   for association field "PersonalBundle\Entity\Group#$defaultClass", got
>   "App\Entity\CustomClass" instead.

As i said it seems not to load the ResolveTargetEntitiesPass... 
Thanks

Comment: Have you added your bundle to `config/bundles.php`? Is your compiler pass executed?

Comment: @malarzm Yes, the bundle is active. How can I check if compiler pass is executed? It seems it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i solved the problem changing the priority of the compiler pass.
I've tried to move the bundle on top in `config/bundle.php` and it started working, then following this https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-compiler-passes-improvements i've left the default type but increased the priority (from 0, default, to 1).
I'm not sure which service has been "downgraded" so if anyone has an idea it's welcome.

```
<?php
// ...
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig;

class PersonalBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container){
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ResolveTargetEntitiesPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, 1);
    }
}
```